# Why is my website taking so long to load on first visit?

Tags: php

I have a website that I built using PHP and HTML hosted on GoDaddy. When the website is idle for more than ~30 minutes, it takes around 20 seconds for it to load on the first visit after that.

I am suspicious that GoDaddy puts the server to sleep if there is no activity for ~30 minutes, but GoDaddy support tells me that is not the case.

I have tried to add session_write_close() just in case there was an issue with session locking. I have also tried clearing my browser cache to see if the website was just loading fast from my cache, but that also did nothing.

Any ideas would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to tell with no information about how the website works.

Comment: "I am suspicious that GoDaddy puts the server to sleep" — It wouldn't surprise me. I haven't heard a good thing about that company ever … and I've known about them for about two decades. I'd look for alternative hosting.

Comment: If you're on shared hosting then you're contending for resources with dozens of other people on an overloaded server. Long story short, any resource your site needs will [probably] be cached in some fashion after pulling it from disk [slow] the first time, and will [probably] stay in cache if it's being touched frequently. After a period of inactivity your stale items will fall out of the cache to make room for other not-stale things. The same goes for DB indexes and so forth. If you want the cache or other resources all to yourself, get a VPS or dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps,

1. make sure images of website are not too big.
2. find out whether any JavaScript is taking too long to load.
3. find out whether any api call is taking too long to return values
4. bad coding can also increase website loading time

you can use this site -> https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

or your google chrome to find out the problem

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.